# How to filter county/locality form

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models County and Locality. When the user signs up I want him to choose a county and locality. I want the locality drop down to contain only the localities that are part of the previously selected county. Can I do that with ruby or do I need javascript or Ajax? I would prefer to keep it in ruby since I don't know anything at all about ajax. Please point me to a relevant resource.

EDIT
I forgot to add that the locality table contains a county_id.

Answer (score 1):

Im sorry but there is no way to do this in ruby you must use ajax. Ruby will need a page refresh to get the localities of the selected country.

Comment: Try jquery post method! You will have to create a new action where u do the searching and then return a json with the localities.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I have found ( Railscasts PRO #088) :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYg6s-b1XGo